# how to change the background color of first row in html table and all other rows alternate color

Tags: html, css

I want to change the background color of first row and all the rest rows underneath it would be alternate color i.e. even odd concept.
currently i am applying `css` for alternate color like this:

```
.table-striped tbody tr:nth-child(odd) td {
    background-color: #81DAF5;
}

.table-striped tbody tr:nth-child(even) td {
    background-color: #CEECF5;
}

.table-striped tbody tr.highlight td {
    background-color: #F2F5A9;
}
```

here, `.table-striped` is table class. So how can i change color for first row in different color like red.

**output of above css:**

[image]

Comment: .table-striped tbody tr:first-child td { background: red; }

Comment: thanks problem solved. Actually, i have make your code statement pasted at end after all even odd css

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use the [:first-child](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:first-child) pseudo class, it's supported by all browsers.

> The :first-child CSS pseudo-class represents any element that is the
>   first child element of its parent.
>
> Syntax element:first-child { style properties }

Added to your CSS:

```
.table-striped tbody tr:nth-child(odd) td {
  background-color: #81DAF5;
}

.table-striped tbody tr:nth-child(even) td {
  background-color: #CEECF5;
}

.table-striped tbody tr.highlight td {
  background-color: #F2F5A9;
}

.table-striped tbody tr:first-child td {
  background-color: #FF0000;
}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zLecmk67/)

**Edit**: As noted by [wrick17](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3339876/wrick17), the added first-child rule should be placed at the bottom since it'll otherwise be overridden.

Comment: wouldn't adding the first-child style to the bottom be safer? since it is going to override the other styles. Sure it works, but wouldn't that be better?

Comment: Thanks for that, you're correct. (It was at the bottom in the JSFiddle and I carelessly added it on top when answering..)

Answer (score 1):

if you specifically want to change the property of first row, use the first-child selector

```
.table-striped tbody tr:first-child td { 
   background: red; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/zgejvLyr/1/

Use first-child css selector

```
.table-striped tbody tr:first-child  td{ 
background-color: red;}
```